# Incrementing a $_GET variable by 1 if a url is clicked

Tags: php, url, variables, get

How do I do this?

I have a variable set

```
if (!isset($_GET['ago']))
```

and i want to increment it by one when this one is click

```
    if (isset($_GET['tod']) && $_GET['tod'] == 'overnight') {

        print ++$_GET['ago'];

    }
```

so if it's clicked I would like 'http://xxxguide?tod=overnight

to actually look like 'http://xxxguide?ago=1&tod=overnight

and everytime 'overnight' is clicked increment 'ago' by 1 so

http://xxxguide?ago=2&tod=overnight
http://xxxguide?ago=3&tod=overnight etc.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` to store `ago` instead!

Comment: you want to redirect a page or what?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning at the top of the page, before any code is written, write the following lines, without any white space characters (like space or carriage return or tab):-

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
```

Now got to your "`if`" block, and modify it according to the following code:-

```
if (isset($_GET['tod']) && $_GET['tod'] == 'overnight') {
    $_SESSION['ago_counter'] = ++$_GET['ago'];
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?ago='.$_SESSION['ago_counter'].'&tod=overnight');
    exit();
}
```

Hope it helps.